# Data Access Audit Log Timestamp for GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I want to measure how long does it take us to upload a file to GCS bucket. In order to do so, we want to get the object creation time.

My first screenshot shows the object info we got from GCS bucket API. the time-stamp shows "2018-01-19T14:58:14.626Z". The second screenshot shows timestamp "14:58:14.574"(different in milliseconds).   According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/audit-logging), in the audit log entry,

> timeStamp contains the time of the audited operation

So I'm assuming that the timestamp I see in the logging entry is the time when storage.objects.create happened.   If I'm not wrong, then what happened in the extra 52 (626-574) milliseconds?

Is it the time that GCS bucket spent from receiving the object creation request to actually get the object written in a disk?

Which timestamp should I use as the time when the object is available for "get" and "download"?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The timestamps are currently assigned separately, so they won't match up exactly. I've filed a feature request internally to make these match and I'll update this answer if/when this change is made.

Comment: sounds good. if they match, are they all meant to represent the time when an object successfully uploaded to GCS and good to get and download ?  right now, which one should I use in my stats?

Comment: do you know more details about GCS? I have another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268822/how-to-check-md5-when-downloading-object-from-gcs , could you shed a light on it too? Thanks!

Comment: The real answer is that the object is ready as soon as the upload returns success. Note that the time on your machine's clock may not match the time on GCS's.

Comment: what do you mean by "time on your machine's clock?"  2018-01-19 14:58:14.574 is from strackdriver logging,  2018-01-19 14:58:14.626 is from GCS object attribute (TimeCreatedRaw). None of the two timestamps are from my machine's clock.   my question now is that which timestamp is when "upload returns success" or "object is ready"

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that neither of those timestamps is how you should decide when an "object is ready". And object is ready for use as soon as you receive an OK response from uploading it.

Comment: then what does the "TimeCreated" mean here?   another team upload the file, so it's not easy for me to get the OK response time. But I really what to measure(or estimate) the upload delay (assuming I have the start timestamp).    I mean, it sounds unreasonable to me  that google log all these timestamps but none of them can be used by its user to measure upload delay....

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "upload delay"? Are you trying to measure the time between when you start the upload and when it finishes? I don't think the audit records have that information. The create time here is when the upload was finalized.